# How To Enable HTTPS filtering with Squid3 and Qlproxy?

Tags: ssl, proxy, squid, content-filter

I'm trying to set my proxy to filter `HTTPS traffic` just like the `HTTP traffic`.

I have followed this guide for [**setup SSLBump**](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/SslBump)

If I set it, even the `HTTP traffic` won't be accepted through the proxy. 
Everything stops.

- How to do it correctly?
- How to let *Qlproxy* to scan and block `HTTPS traffic`?

<sub>**Please consider me as a newbie to this field.**</sub>

Comment: any errors ? tcpdump sniff ? you must be extremely verbose.

Comment: Have you forwarded outgoing https port (443) to the port which squid3 proxy uses?

Answer (score 1):

The newly released version of qlproxy is able to filter HTTPS traffic, the virtual appliance on quintolabs.com has everything already in place to do the SSL bump. Online documentation of Diladele Web Safety (new name for qlproxy) shows exact steps how to configure and recompile your Squid on Ubuntu 13.10 to perform HTTPS filtering and SSL Bump.